# Inventory tool for managing projects

Tags: project-management, inventory

We are a little web agency and we're looking for an tool in which we can manage our (web) projects.

Each project has the basic stuff like "lead", "co-workers", "contact person",... etc. But besides the obvious, we also must be able to add different data-sets on each project.
Every project had also multiple environments (dev, staging, production,...) so we must be able to provide each environment with the same data, specific for that environment.
For example, not all projects will have a Solr or Elastic integration, but some do. Solr data will be different for dev, staging and production.
Passwords are listed as well, so if there is some kind of integrated password manager, would be great as well (now we're using LastPass/Dashlane, but they don't for-fill our needs).

We're basically looking for a tool on which you can add custom "entities" (if I may describe it like this) on each project.

A plus would we if we could filter and search on all the data. "Give me all the projects running on a Solr 6", "export all Drupal 7.54 projects in one JSON",...

Comment: Have you looked at Redmine ?